# My jQuery.ajax request POST data in PHP backend can not get

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use my jQuery ajax to request PHP backend:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            qn_action: 'bmc',
            action: 'productdetails',
            id: 772,
            server_name: 'LL-01',
            tblclients_id: 1,
            bmc_action: 'on',
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus){

            console.log('ldl:',data)

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, e) {
            var msg = '';
            if(jqXHR.status==0){
                msg = 'You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.';
            }else if(jqXHR.status==404){
                msg = 'Requested URL not found.';
            }else if(jqXHR.status==500){
                msg = 'Internal Server Error.<br/>'+jqXHR.responseText;
            }else if(e=='parsererror'){
                msg = 'Error: Parsing JSON Request failed.';
            }else if(e=='timeout'){
                msg = 'Request Time out.';
            }else {
                msg = 'Unknow Error.<br/>'+x.responseText;
            }

            console.log('error: '+jqXHR.responseText);
            console.log('Error msg: '+msg);
        }
    })
```

In the PHP backend:

I want to check the request data:

```
echo json_encode(
  parse_str($_POST['qn_action'])
);
```

there will get `ldl: – null` in the browser console.

if I use

```
echo json_encode(
  $_POST['qiyun02_action']
);
```

still get `ldl: – null`.

if I use

```
echo json_encode(
  $_POST
);
```

I will get `ldl: []`.

so, how can I get the data from jQuery ajax request?

Comment: you can get data of `$_POST` easily just remove `dataType` from ajax request and do `$_POST['qn_action']` on server side.

Comment: if the ajax have a default `dataType`?

Comment: do not worry about default, it set based on return data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP code probably missing header for json.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Because you have defined `JSON` in your jquery

```
dataType: 'json',
```

so server expect json result. As docs say

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.