# how to display json object using jquery

Tags: jquery

I could't get json object value could you please let me know and jsfiddle example.

jquery Code:

```js
    $("document").ready(function(){         
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/ui%20works/jsonobject.json',
                success: function(callback) {
                    console.log(callback);
                    ordersList=callback;
                    console.log(ordersList['RestResponse']['result']["country"]);
                },
                error: function() {
                    $(this).html("error!");
                }
            });
      });
```

my json:

```
    {
      "RestResponse" : {
        "messages" : [ "Total [5] records found." ],
        "result" : [ {
          "country" : "IND",
          "name" : "Andhra Pradesh" 
        }, {
          "country" : "AUS",
          "name" : "Andhra Pradesh" 
        } ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: your json is response?

Comment: my json response undefined. i want to country details.

Answer (score 0):

If your response is json then you need add option [dataType](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/) into your ajax.

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Then javascript object is returned and you can use

```
success: function(callback) {
    for(var i=0; i<callback.RestResponse.result.length; i++) {
        console.log(callback.RestResponse.result[i].country);
    }
```

You need also use loop because `result` is an array.

Comment: Thanks for your help i am using above method but not working same problem of undefined could you please help me another method.

Comment: Your server need send json response with json header like my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58161727/my-jquery-ajax-request-post-data-in-php-backend-can-not-get/58161845#58161845

Comment: Also you should verify if your json is valid, you can check it here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/